# про свойство класса

Tags: php, ооп

Есть класс А , в нем определены  статично-публичное св-во $price и публичный статичный  метод meth  с данным св-вом $price, который присваивает внутри класса значение (self). 
есть класс B потомок класса А. Метод класса переопределен, внутри  свойство $price класса А задано через ::parent.
Вопрос, 
почему это свойство;$price пустое, если к нему обратится как A::$price?
и как получить правильное значение...?

```html
class A {
    //public static $price; 
 static $orderPrice   = false;
 
    public static function meth() {
        //self::$price = 1;
  // здесь формирование массива $goods.
     $goods=array("0"=>1,"1"=>2);
        self::setGoods($goods);
  return $goods;
    }
 public static function setGoods($arOrderGoods){
  self::$goods = false;
  
  if(!self::$orderPrice){
   self::$orderPrice = 0;
   foreach($arOrderGoods as $arGood)
    self::$orderPrice += $arGood ;
  }
 }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function meth($id) {
     // здесь формирование массива $goods.
     $goods=array("0"=>1,"1"=>2);
        parent::setGoods($goods);
  return $goods;
    }
}

$ooods=B::meth();
echo A::$orderPrice; //"ничего не делает"
```

Если бы не было класса B, то A::$orderPrice; возвращает нормальный рез-т.
пробовала B::$orderPrice пустое значение...
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы класс А не менять, чтобы решить данный вопрос.

PS Если Вам известны хорошие ресурсы -практикуумы с ответами и объяснениями про классы пхп... Очень прошу сказать-)

Comment: вы попробуйте вместо того что описывать текстом что у вас в коде, просто привести этот код, куда понятнее будет

Comment: В последней редакции вопроса: $goods не определена; B:meth() принимает аргумент $id, тогда как A:meth() - нет. И вы напрасно меняете суть вопроса на лету и переписываете его, из-за этого связь с принятым ответом теряется. Соответственно и пропадает ценность данного вопроса для базы знаний stakoverflow. С уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конструкция `A::$price;` обращается на прямую переменной до вызова метода, присваивающего ей значение . Т.к. метод `meth()` у вас так и не был вызван, значит `$price = null`.

```
class A
{
    public static $price;

    public static function meth($value)
    {
        self::$price = $value;
        return static::$price; // LSB
    }
}

class B extends A
{

    public static $price;

    public static function meth($value)
    {
        parent::$price = $value;
        return A::$price;
    }
}

echo is_null(A::$price);   // 1

echo A::meth("value A");   // value A

echo B::meth("value B");   // value B
```

Comment: Посмотрите,пж-ста, я обновила ответ,
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы класс А не менять, чтобы решить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Нормально всё отрабатывает т.к. для статических методов и свойств действуют те же правила:

```
class A {
    public static $a;

    public static function getA() {
        self::$a = 'lala';
        return self::$a;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function getA() {
        parent::$a = 'test';
        return A::$a;
    }
}

echo 'A::$a = '.A::getA().'; B::$a = '.B::getA();
```

Comment: Посмотрите,пж-ста, я обновила ответ,
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы класс А не менять, чтобы решить данный вопрос?